# Location hash on linkedin, can't figure out how to produce/modify

Tags: frontend, linkedin-api

Im a programmer for a small digital marketing company in Maryland and I was told to automate the process of finding competitors in a specific industry. Linkedin's database of companies is perfect, however the only issue Im running into is the location feature. Linkedin creates some kind of hash for locations that they pass on as a query in thier URLs, and I can't figure out where they're getting this number from.

Here is what I mean:

> [https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?**companyHqGeo=["102221843"]**&industryCompanyVertical=["42"%2C"25"%2C"27"]&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&sid=B%40S](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?**companyHqGeo=%5B%22102221843%22%5D**&industryCompanyVertical=%5B%2242%22%2C%2225%22%2C%2227%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&sid=B%40S)

the companyHqGeo=["102221843"] portion, I can't understand where that is coming from. LinkedIn allows for automation and web scraping of public material, so this is legal to do, but I need assistance getting this last portion of the queries.

Please reach out to a programmer who worked on this portion of the website, it'd be much appreciated.

Best,

I tried searching online to see if there was some kind of global location converting algorithim that they were using and all I could find was GLN, but it ins't applicable, at least I dont think so.